# Dynamically added form elements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This question is basically for my understanding, so kindly guide me. I dont require any code but just the approach for solving this type of problem.

I am using jquery to dynamically add form elements. For example, I want user to enter his favourite movie. I have given him an add button to add more movies. Now if user adds 10 times for 10 movies, how will i save this data to database ? i mean i will have only one column for movie but user is entering 10 (some might add 100) so how is this data stored ?

I have asked this question to basically understands how to save data when the form elements are dynamically added ? shall i save them to column movies and seperate them by commas or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approach to solve this problem. One solution to this is AJAX. say example you are using php

1) Sort form data with each use press button; jQuery Form.

2) a php function to process sql queries.

3) call php function in ajax in success method.

4) store value in database.

Comment: point 4 is the actual confusion. How am i suppose to store values when i dont know how many there will be ???

Answer (score 0):

In the form elements that you add, you would make the `name=` value into an array, so that the various identical items could be processed.

For example, suppose you are cloning a table row. Suppose this is the template row that you are cloning:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Movie Name: <input type="text" name="mov[]" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

After the form was posted, the data would appear something like this:

```
POST DATA:
Array
(
    [mov] => Array
         (
             [0] =>           (the initial, template row would have no value)
             [1] => Gladiator (whatever user typed in)
             [2] => Troy      (the next movie entered by user...
```

---

The code I used to view the POST output above looks like this:

```
If (empty($_POST)===false) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'POST DATA:<br />';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '<br />*********************************************************<br /><br />';
    echo 'UPLOADED FILES:<br />';
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo '</pre>';
    die('Dying immed inside IF EMPTY($_POST)===FALSE...');
}
```